# Why can't I login to Web UI after install of Ubuntu 18 MAAS?

Tags: server, juju, maas

I downloaded the ISO for Ubuntu.  I am asking about how I can learn more about installing MAAS.  During installation from my boot disk, it offered 3 options, (1) Install Ubuntu server, (2) MAAS regional and (3) MAAS rack.  It was an Ubuntu server live iso.  I have been meaning to learn about type 1 hypervisors for my IT skills advancement.  So, MAAS is supposed to be bare metal type 1 hypervisor/virtualization.  So, why does it appear to install a full copy of Ubuntu?

My second question is about accessing the web-based control panel from a second computer in the same LAN.  I got an error saying that the target device actively refused the connection.  This is immediately following installation.

Can someone explain this to me and then refer me to further training online?

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 1):

> MAAS is supposed to be bare metal type 1 hypervisor/virtualization. So, why does it appear to install a full copy of Ubuntu?

MAAS is a tool for provisioning OS images onto blank bare metal machines, and high level management of those machines - it has a powerful API that can be used to allocate and release machines for a specific purpose on demand.

One way of doing this is by using [Juju](https://jujucharms.com/) to allocate and configure resources from MAAS' machine pool.

MAAS can also deploy OS images as VMs using KVM onto target nodes as 'Pods'.  This requires the target nodes to have the KVM Hypervisor installed.

MAAS server service itself is installed onto an Ubuntu host OS, and there are several ways to accomplish this - the [MAAS documentation](https://docs.maas.io/) does a great job of covering this in detail.